# Bluetooth Mouse keeps connect/disconnect without move

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to setup a bluetooth mouse, without success.

I'm using Fedora 29, but I've also tested on an Debian Distro and the problem is the same, so I thought that could not be a distro specific related problem...

Mouse works, I've tested on a windows machine.

Bluetoothctl shows connect/disconnect every second, also the mouse never moves...

Bellow, some traces:

Bluez installed: bluez-5.50-3.fc29.src.rpm (Bluez 5.50 x86_74)

```
sudo hcitool info 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE
Requesting information ...
    BD Address:  00:1F:20:8E:20:CE
    OUI Company: Logitech Europe SA (00-1F-20)
    Device Name: Dell Travel Mouse WM524
    LMP Version: 3.0 (0x5) LMP Subversion: 0x2211
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
    Features page 0: 0xbc 0x04 0x82 0x78 0x00 0x06 0x59 0x83
        <encryption> <slot offset> <timing accuracy> <role switch> 
        <sniff mode> <channel quality> <paging scheme> 
        <broadcast encrypt> <enhanced iscan> <interlaced iscan> 
        <interlaced pscan> <inquiry with RSSI> <sniff subrating> 
        <pause encryption> <extended inquiry> <simple pairing> 
        <encapsulated PDU> <non-flush flag> <LSTO> <inquiry TX power> 
        <extended features> 
    Features page 1: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Bluetooth Status

```
 systemctl status bluetooth:

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-06 01:05:47 -02; 18min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 821 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─821 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for Message Notification: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for Message Access: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for Phone Book Access: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for Synchronization: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for File Transfer: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:06:03 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: RFCOMM server failed for Object Push: socket(STREAM, RFCOMM): Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 06 01:07:01 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: Can't open HIDP control socket
Feb 06 01:07:02 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: Rejected connection from unknown device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE
Feb 06 01:13:04 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: Can't open HIDP control socket
Feb 06 01:13:09 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[821]: connect error: Host is down (112)
```

With bluetoothctl I can pair the device:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE 
Attempting to pair with 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Modalias: usb:v046DpB00Ed0800
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE UUIDs: 00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE UUIDs: 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: no
```

After pairing I try to connect, then.....:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE Connected: no
```

What could be happening?

Comment: same issue on a DREVO keyboard on Fedora 31, no luck with the trust trick

Comment: @thomas8 use 'setenforce 0' to disable SElinux

Comment: @Thomas8 use 'setenforce 0'

Comment: no benefits with selinux, in fact there's no AVC errors in audit.log when the keyboard disconnects briefly

Comment: Even journalctl shows nothing?

Comment: A lot of error, but not understandable: https://pastebin.com/gR78BMGb
I would like to try a firmware update with the official Drevo program but it only works on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @Thomas8 maybe you should try to update your BlueZ driver, what version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

what a lucky, I just tried `[bluetooth]# trust 00:1F:20:8E:20:CE` and worked!

But I've tried this before without success, the difference is now I tried to trust when the mouse is on **pairing mode**... This seems to have a huge difference.

If I trust without in the pairing mode, nothing happens.

Comment: Another thing you should try is to check SELinux. try `setenforce 0` before connecting the bluetooth device

Comment: nuking SELinux is almost never the solution, it opens the machine up to all sort of "interesting" activities.

Comment: Yes, one could try adding custom SE rules for the bluetooth only